# Episerver Admin Login Details

Tags: episerver

I am creating a scheduled job in episerver with some business criteria.One entry point to this business criteria is to get the admin login details(name,email,etc).

With **EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name** ,it only gives me Given name that is not helpful.I need other details ie email,id to make some other logged in used based call.
Is there a way to get the logged in admin details.

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled jobs does not run under a certain user. PrincipalInfo.CurrenPrincipal will only give your principal when you run the job manually. What you need is available through the ASP.NET Identity services, given that's your configured login provider.